# When to use git push -u?

Tags: git

Most of the time I use `git push origin master` to update my code.

When I set up a new repo today github suggests using `git push -u origin master`. Had read the manpage but still no idea. What is the difference between these two commands?

Comment: `-u` is short for `--set-upstream`, which just lets you use commands like `git push` and `git pull` without specifying which remote to push/pull from. Since you've almost certainly set your upstream branches already, you won't see any difference.

Comment: It's a fair question, though. As so often, the docs are pretty opaque. I can certainly see how "For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1) and other commands" might not communicate much to one's mind.